# 'dependsOn' property error in data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am getting following error in azure data factory pipeline activity

I am using following code:

```
...
"dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "MyFirstActivity",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        }
      ]
...
```

> "Input is malformed. Reason: batchPipelineRequest.dependsOn : Could not find member 'dependsOn' on object of type 'Activity'. Path 'dependsOn'..
>   OK"

Is there any other property we need to put in pipeline or in datasets?

Comment: Just to double check you are using data factory v2 (currently in public preview), as this isn't a feature of v1? If not could you post a little more of your pipeline please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available only in v2 preview version of ADF. To link and activity to another activity, you will need to use the output of previous activity as the input to the new activity. You can find details here-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-create-pipelines